# Convert a double* one-dimensional matrix to double** 2D square matrix

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix

I have a one-dimensional representation of a matrix: of type

```
double *A1d;
```

You may assume that this data structure is `malloc'd` and filled with double values and is of length `MATRIX_SIZE * MATRIX_SIZE`.

I would like to convert this data structure into a two-dimensional square matrix of type `double**` with row/column length `MATRIX_SIZE`

I am looking for something like:

```
double** A2D = vector_to_matrix(int sz, double* matrix_1d);
```

Comment: `typedef double M2D_row[MATRIX_SIZE]; M2D_row *A2D = (M2D_row *) A1D;`? You can do it without the `typedef`, but I find that syntax cleaner... And this avoids all the re-allocation/copying overhead. Although it is sidestepping the type system, type-punning, and all that... Better to just declare it as what you want it to be to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple algorithm can be applied to convert your one-dimensional matrix to a two-dimensional square matrix.

The following function will accomplish this assuming your 1D matrix is of the correct size for this mapping:

```
double** vector_to_matrix(int sz, double* matrix_1d)
{
  double** matrix_2d;
  matrix_2d = (double**) malloc(sz*sizeof(double*));

  for (int k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
    matrix_2d[k] = (double*) malloc(sz*sizeof(double));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    for (int j = sz * i; j < sz * (i+1); j++) {
      matrix_2d[i][j%sz] = matrix_1d[j];
    }
  }
  return matrix_2d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double** vector_to_matrix(int sz, double* matrix_1d) {
  // The output 2d matrix to be returned.
  double** matrix_2d = (double**)malloc(sz * sizeof(double*));

  // Allocate memory.
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    matrix_2d[i] = (double*)malloc(sz * sizeof(double));

  // Copy from 1d matrix.
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++) matrix_2d[i][j] = matrix_id[i * sz + j];

  return matrix_2d;
}
```